# Existe algum recurso para pesquisar somente perguntas fechadas?

Tags: suporte, perguntas-fechadas

Todas perguntas que são fechadas por alguma razão, o sistema acrescenta a palavra [pendente|duplicada] no titulo da mesma, gostaria de pesquisar elas, se na caixa de pesquisa tentar [pendente], automaticamente ele associa a tag [pendente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pendente), tentei também pelo endereço [/questions?sort=pending](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=pending) e nada, enfim, existe algum modo de pesquisar somente por perguntas que estão fechadas?

Talvez exista alguma query já pronta no [data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Isso?  `closed:yes` na busca?